# Big PDF file when language is PL (Polish)

Tags: pdf, abap

I converted a Smart Form output into PDF using the function module `SX_OBJECT_CONVERT_OTF_PDF`.

My problem is that when the language is PL (Polish) the PDF file is 10 times bigger comparing to EN language. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Gunstick answer is probably right.
Sap note: 843480 discuss this issue.

As of release 620 onward, there is support patches that enable pdf elements( such as fonts) to be compressed. The resulting pdf will be larger then the only English one, but it will probably be less than 10 times larger.

Answer (score 2):

This may be that polish uses a specific font (special characters) which is not installed by default on an OS. So the pdf converter includes the complete font into the document in order to render it correctly at the destination.

This is just speculation though.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this one: http://lucattelli.com/blog/?page_id=478

This FM can take the binary PDF and convert it to BASE 64 and send it as a mail attachment.

See if it helps